# отладка Android studio

Tags: android-studio, отладка

Как понять на какой строчке кода ошибка по сообщению в Android Monitor? 
Например:

```
08-22 10:34:38.495 2662-2662/com.example.pavel.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.pavel.myapplication, PID: 2662
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pavel.myapplication/com.example.pavel.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Возможно, я ошибаюсь, но, кажется, у Вас ошибка и не в коде. Обычно такая ошибка (Unable to start activity ComponentInfo) возникает, когда в файле манифеста забыли прописать Activity

Comment: Соответственно, ни на какую строку кода указания быть и не может.

Comment: Собственно у вас падение при попытке программно добавить вьюху в `LinearLayout` который `null`. Скорее всего в логах ошибки далее, которые вы не привели и есть конкретная строка падения.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, спасибо! Да, так и есть, там дальше продолжение и синим подчеркнуто конкретная строка из-за которой не работает. Я просто когда выкладывал, об этом не знал и думал, указание на ошибку указано где-то в первых строках.